# How to use MVP with Viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mvp

I am new to applying `MVP to android` use. 
i want to create a Activity that holds Viewpager. the Adapter of viewpager contains fragments with data .

i have made the view presenter for my activity. my question is : is it important to make view presenter for each fragment of the viewpager? i mean am not getting any proper sample on MVP . can any one provide some good guide tutorials !!

do we have to create view-presenter for adapters too??

Activity has a model view and presented 
Fragment has a model view presenter 
Adapters also a model view presenter

what is the correct implementation ?? any guide anything will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your viewpager adapter will communicate with Activity. Viewpager do not have to do anything with MVP, when you get the data response in activity. Then just update the viewpager adapter with data.